# Verb or predicate adjective?

Tags: verbs, linking-verbs, predicate-adjectives

In this sentence, is the verb "is" or "is central"?

> The principle that an action must be judged on the basis of its foreseeable consequences is central to many areas of the law

I thought the verb is just "is" with "central" being an adjective, but my LSAT study material indicates the verb is "is central".

Comment: Suppose you omit the unnecessary words, leaving "... is [central to many areas of] the law." What is the verb?

Comment: No, central is no verb here. It works like: is key, is important, is vital, is logical.

Comment: What *exactly* does the study material say? Can you link to the source? You're right but it'd be better if we could tell you why.

Comment: *Central* is a keyword here, but doesn't become a verb. "The principle is good." Good is not a verb.

Comment: @alphabet all it says is the sentence and points out the subject is "principle" and verb is "is central". No reason is given. It's a membership only site, so I am unable to link to it.

Comment: @AfterWorkGuinness In that case, their answer is so blatantly wrong that it should call the site's value into question.

Comment: The LSAT is wrong. "Is central" is not a constituent at word level. "Is" is a verb functioning as predicator and "central" is an adjective functioning as head of the adjective phrase "central to many areas of the law".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re correct, the verb is *is*. It functions as a standard copula here, linking the subject (*principle*) to a predicate adjective (*central*) as you say. In some cases the line between verb phrase and copula + subject complement may be blurred (i.e., passive verbs vs. participial adjectives)—but *central* is clearly not a verb form in any sense . . . so where they came up with that classification is beyond me. I’d imagine, though, that an LSAT study guide is not necessarily the ideal resource for grammatical guidance (nor would it have much of a reason to be).

Comment: I'd say that the subject is the whole of the NP _the principle that an action must be judged on the basis of its foreseeable consequences_.

Comment: Functionally, yes, I’d agree that the whole NP is the subject. But when parsing a sentence I tend to refer to the heads of such phrases—the syntactically “essential” parts—as subject or predicate rather than the whole phrase. And perhaps that’s a relic of my younger education.

Comment: I suggest you ditch any relics of your younger education and concentrate on accurate syntactic analyses. It's the only way to avoid misunderstandings. If you must cite just the heads of phrases, then you should make that clear in your answers.